# Effect of Coriolis force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, coriolis-effect

Is [Coriolis force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force) fictitious in an inertial frame or not? If so can it be mathematically deduced using an inertial frame as reference?

Comment: Please see [our guide](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) on writing good titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fictitious forces do not exist in inertial frames. Fictitious forces result from force-fitting Newtonian mechanics to non-inertial frames.

Comment: Yah that's correct but can we deduce the equation for coriolis force from an inertial frame

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the question.